# Confused about the grammar of "good mood" and "good spirits"

Tags: grammar, compound-words

consider this  [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319607/why-do-we-use-singular-form-a-mood-not-mood/319610?noredirect=1#comment727047_319610)

"Good mood" here, the word "good" clearly describes the word "mood". As far as I am concerned, I could change the word "good" in any other words that would be able to describe "mood".

On the latter part of the link is were my question comes.

"I am in good spirits" - We know that this particular sentence is correct. My question is, is "good spirits" considered as a compound word here? If not, why did it become correct, even if it lacks a determiner?

---

just to clarify

As we know, a [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250702/are-they-in-a-good-mood-or-in-good-moods) here explains that "in a good mood" was the correct usage, but it does not explain why we say "in a good mood" as oppose to "in good mood" just like in good company, in good standing, in good time, in good conscience, in good condition, in good stead which are all grammatically correct.

I really cannot find any suitable explanation for this thing.

---

By the way I already understand regarding the singular and plural matter.

Comment: The question that you linked to has a new answer, which suggests that the "determiner" is optional when the noun is plural.  For example, "I have a cat. I have apples."  (Or I could say "I have some apples" or "I have three apples.")  Hence, "**a** good mood", but "good spirit**s**".

Comment: Thanks! Looks, like this is the actual answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Scott could you kindly explain this `in good company, in good standing, in good time, in good conscience, in good condition, in good stead.`

Comment: Fer cryin' out loud!  **"MOOD" IS SINGULAR, "SPIRITS" IS PLURAL!!!**  (Other terms may lack an article because they are "mass nouns" -- same difference.)

Comment: sorry edited the question of the reason why I put the bounty

Comment: question was based on the previous comment of mine more than a year ago

Comment: I don't fully follow the logic of your question. Moods can be *good* or *foul*, and spirits can be *high* or *dampened*, etc. Have a look at the examples in [ODO noun definition 2.3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/spirit).

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250702/are-they-in-a-good-mood-or-in-good-moods

Comment: why is the phrase "in good mood" wrong?

Comment: You should put all relevant information into the text of your question. Otherwise, we wouldn't know what you were reading or thinking about at the time you asked your question. For example, include the full sentence for which you considered the phrase "in good mood" to be wrong.

Comment: I'll edit this again later on our lunch break.

Comment: To help with your editing: as the question stands, it looks to me as if you're asking whether "good spirits" is a compound word for which, idiomatically, *good* cannot be changed to something else, with "good spirits" used in the sense of "good mood".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though *mood* (and *state of mind*) can be described in gradations — *good, better, fine, awful*, etc. — I think we nevertheless understand *mood* in a specific sense. In the case of "in a good mood", I think *good* is being used less as a gradation and more as something synonymous with *happy* or *content*.

In contrast, if I say "I am in good health," I am conveying my overall, general health and its state on a continuous scale. I can't be specific about a particular physical condition when I say, "I am in X health", I can only express an X degree of wellness.

Unlike general nouns in this context, *mood* can take adjectives such as *happy*, *angry*, *sad*, *romantic*, *sentimental*, *silly*, and many more which are not gradations, but specific states that serve to describe a particular mood. And, in its specificity, it requires the article *a*.

Comment: how about "in good condition"

Comment: seen this link https://www.italki.com/question/66234 thanks

Comment: @ArchieAzares I believe the meaning of condition hinges on whether the subject is animate or inanimate. For humans and other living creatures, *condition* is almost always synonymous with the general word *health*, but for inanimate objects, it can mean either *health* or the more specific *state*. General: "The bridge is in poor condition." Specific: "The bridge is in a deteriorating condition."

Answer (score -5):

I dont think the term "good spirits" is a compound word, since there are cases where the sentense "(someone is) in bad spirits." is used. I personally think the reason why you don't hear it as much has something to do with the Bible. Bad spirits = Evil spirit, maybe ??